# unable to call the object in android studio

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

I got this problem that I'm unable to call the object ID. I'm not quite sure what is wrong with the code. I'm quite new in kotlin android development btw.
I'll appreciate any advise. TIA!
Please see code below.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View { 
val animal = listOfAnimals[position] 
var inflator = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater 
var myView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.animal_ticket, null) 
myView.**tvName.text** = animal.name!! 
myView.**tvDes.text** = animal.des!! 
myView.**ivAnimaLimage**.setImageResource(animal.image!!) 
return myView
```

Comment: Are you putting in the astrik? If so Kotlin Synthetics don't require the astriks, they do require an import though, you will need something like this in your imports list
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity_main.*

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but the values in the asterisk were the ones that can't be called.